# using implode to combine multiple select

Tags: php

I have a php page like  this :

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="catch_combo.php">
            <select name="selr[]" multiple>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to catch the selected values in catch_combo.php which looks like this:

```
<?php
$two;
    if(isset($_REQUEST['selr']))
        {
        $one=$_POST['selr'];
        foreach ($one as $a) 
        {
        $two = implode(",", $a);
        }
        echo $two;
        }
        ?>
```

When I run this it says

'Invalid arguments passed for implode' I am missing something?

Comment: Run a print_r($_REQUEST['selr']) - it doesn't contain the value you think it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$two = '';

if(isset($_REQUEST['selr']))
{

    $one=$_POST['selr'];
    foreach ($one as $a=>$value) 
    {
        $two .= ', '.$value;
    }
    echo $two;
}
```

No need for implode.

Answer (score 1):

but easier way is:

```
$two = implode(',', $_POST['selr']);
```

Answer (score 0):

The question was about invalid arguments passed for `implode()`

The 2nd argument for `implode()` must be an array.

$a in your sample code is *not* an array.

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing an array to `implode()`, that's why it complains. Try this:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['selr'])) {
    echo implode(',', $_REQUEST['selr']);
}
```